# What's the difference in the order of applying selectors

Tags: html, css

The task was to set red color to all paragraphs in the class `standart`

I did it this way

```
.standart p { color:red; }
```

but I was told it's bad solution and this is the "good one"

```
p.standart { color:red; }
```

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: Take a look at [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). The first is a [*descendant combinator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators).

Comment: If you don’t appreciate the difference please take the time to read about [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors).

Answer (score 3):

```css
.standart p { color:red; }
p.standart { color:red; }
```

```html
<div class="standart">
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<p class="standart">One 1</p>
<p class="standart">Two 2</p>
<p class="standart">Three 3</p>
```

.standart p { color:red; } means you want red color text for all paragraphs inside standart class.

p.standart { color:red; } means you want red color text for all paragraphs having standart class.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The first one matches each `<p>` element descendant of an element with the `standard` class (for example: `<div class="standard"><p>` ), whereas the second one matches all `<p>` elements with class `standard` ( `<p class='standard'>` ). None of them is incorrect, depends on what you need.

Comment: Oh I see, but if the task was given like that then I completed the task or not?

Comment: @P.Bolfa What??

Comment: In that task only the second one is correct

Comment: If the task says "Set red color to all paragraphs inside the class standart then ```.standart p``` will work just fine?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your previous comment, if the task had been to set red all the paragaphs inside an element with class standard then the `.standard p` would have been correct. It's also fair to say Kumar Gaurav gave you the best answer, you could mark his answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

**The difference is below**

`.standart p { color:red; } - it applies on all paragraph text inside the standard class.
 p.standart { color:red; } - it applies on all paragraphs text which having the standard class.`